# How is the graph $K_m^n$ defined?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading Diestel's Graph Theory but I can't find a definition for $K_m^n$. How should I draw graphs like these?

Comment: @Hendrix you should turn your comment into an answer. ☺

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn done :). I suppose that aids those that filter by unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

On Pg $17$, Section $1.6$, the definition of $K^r_s$ is given. I found this by looking at the symbol index in the back. I'm using the fifth edition. Lots of well written books should have some version of a symbol index.